# ¿Como atar una sentencia con inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Esta es primera tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PSDocumentosCarga
(nId int  identity (1,1)not null,
nIdDocumento int   NULL,
nContratoP char(14)  NULL,
cNombreDoc varchar(max)  NULL,
cRutaDoc varchar(max)  NULL,
cCodDoc varchar(max)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY(nId)
)
GO
```

Esta es mi segunda tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PSDocumentosCompaginar
(nId int primary key identity (1,1),
nIdDocumento int  NULL,
cDocumentoBynario varbinary(max)  NULL,
cNomCampo varchar(250) NULL,
cCodDoc varchar(max) NULL,
constraint fk1 foreign key (nId)
references dbo.PSDocumentosCarga(nId)
)
GO
```

Mi consulta insert into para consultar y guardar en mi segunda tabla

```
    INSERT INTO PSDocumentosCompaginar  (nIdDocumento,cDocumentoBynario, cNomCampo,cCodDoc)
    SELECT 5, BULKCOLUMN, 'AUTORIZACION BURO', 'AB005'
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Queries\Carga de Datos\B0020000000138\AB005.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS DOCUMENT
inner join PSDocumentosCompaginar  C on C.nIdDocumento= PSDocumentosCarga.nIdDocumento
```

Intento agregar un `inner join`, para relacionar los campos `nIdDocumento`, pero devuelve un error.

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 55 The multi-part identifier
> "PSDocumentosCarga.nIdDocumento" could not be bound.

Comment: El alias de el PDF es `DOCUMENT`, no `PSDocumentosCarga`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que contiene la select no pertene aún a `PSDocumentosCompaginar` por tanto no puede saber unir la tabla.

La solución más simple es utilizar una tabla derivada para disponer de los nombres de columnas:

```
  INSERT INTO PSDocumentosCompaginar  (nIdDocumento,cDocumentoBynario, cNomCampo,cCodDoc)
    Select d.* from (
    SELECT 5 AS nIdDocumento, BULKCOLUMN as cDocumentoBynario , 'AUTORIZACION BURO' as cNomCampo, 'AB005' as cCodDoc
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'd:\temp\processlist.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS DOCUMENT
    ) as d
    inner join PSDocumentosCompaginar  C on C.nIdDocumento= d.nIdDocumento;
```

Comment: Gracias, ¿que pasara que lo ejecuto? pero no guarda. 0 celdas afectadas

Comment: Quita el insert into y que te devuelve???. Si te devuelve alguna row, es posible que openRowSet no tenga privilegios para leer el archivo, porque estas en una carpeta de usuario. Haz la prueba primero copiando el archivo en c:\temp o algo del estilo. No en el raiz, ni en mis documentos ni nada similar.  Sino comentas.